# How do I quote the C++ Standard?

Tags: discussion

I find that sometimes in answering or reading answers to C/C++ questions on SO, I have to quote/read some clauses from the C standard or C++ standard. Is there a convention or even standard way to read or quote the standard(s)? Essentially, what is the conventional way to read/quote the standard(s) and is there some references for such?

Thanks

Comment: it's a bit off-topic, isn't it?

Comment: You just refer to the documents as you would refer to any other documents. What's the question?

Comment: Are you asking how to format your quotes, or how to get access to the standard text? The answer to the second part is that you can buy them in .pdf format from the [ANSI webstore](http://webstore.ansi.org/)

Comment: You can't quote, it is copyright-ed material whose license you cannot change to CC.  Post the chapter/paragraph number, re-interpret what it says.  Which makes it a better answer, the standard is dense as a brick.

Comment: @Hans Passant - Of course you can quote small sections as part of a discussion on what the standard says. Rephrasing, or translation into German, will not help you avoid the copyright anyway. Posting **only** a quote could possibly be an infringement though.

Comment: "You can't quote"? I see a lot of quotes(copy paste of paragraphs) on Stackoverflow in answering some questions. Do these quotes violate copyright?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A standard for the standard? How quaint!

Being able to weave in references isn't really much of a convention. When it's appropriate to substantiate your answer, add in an in-place quote - hyperlink your text to the relevant section of the standard, or make a statement and then support it with the standard (make sure that you add in the reference to the section/subsection/etc, in the form A.B.C).

As for *reading* the standard, I prefer doing so with a bottle of scotch. It's far more interesting that way.

Comment: Regarding hyperlinking: here's one site, to subpages of which you can usefully hyperlink: https://github.com/timsong-cpp/cppwp (see the HTML versions of various drafts). That's not the Standard itself, only drafts, but it's good enough in most cases.